# Python - to_csv - cannot find directory /iPython notebook can

Tags: python, windows, pandas, directory, ipython

I have written a small Python script to extract data and save it with pandas as a CSV file in a folder in a shared drive called 'N:\folder\'. The function used is:

```
df.to_csv('N:\MMS Managers\house_opportunities.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

It works well when I run my code in iPython notebook but if I run exactly the same via the command line it crashes and says:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'N:\\MMS Managers\\house_opportunities.csv'
```

I am running it on Windows
Does anyone know how to fix that please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work running it via cmd.exe, I think the unix bash emulator I was using didn't recognize this N:/ drive.

Thanks!

Comment: Was the bash shell elevated? Mapped drives may depend on cached credentials, so Windows defines them per logon session. An administrator's elevated token is actually for a different logon session, so you have to map the drive again using, for example, an elevated command prompt and the `net use` command.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to the double slashes you see in the error:

```
'N:\\MMS Managers\\house_opportunities.csv'
```

Thus, I would suggest trying first to give the path to **os.path.abspath**, which should take care of the double slashes, and then use df.to_csv:

```
import os
path = os.path.abspath('N:\MMS Managers\house_opportunities.csv')
df.to_csv(path, index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer lev!

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the same error after doing that

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't help. Anyway, knowing about the os.path utilities could be helpful to you in the future. At least, I hope so :)

Comment: I've read about the workaround you found. Have you also tried using the windows [powershell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell)?

Comment: The double slashes are because Python escapes backslashes when making the string's repr. They're not really double in the string itself. I.e. `\n` = newline, but `\\n` = backslash,  n.